# URI when including aggregate information in RESTful response

Tags: rest, aggregate, restful-url

Let's say I have a RESTful API method to return data about a series of locations:

/locations

```
[{
  location_id: 1,
  location_name: 'Austin'
},{
  location_id: 2,
  location_name: 'San Francisco'
},{
  location_id: 3,
  location_name: 'Seattle'
}]
```

Now let's say I want to return an aggregate employee_count for each location:

```
[{
  location_id: 1,
  location_name: 'Austin',
  employee_count: 96
},{
  location_id: 2,
  location_name: 'San Francisco',
  employee_count: 71
},{
  location_id: 3,
  location_name: 'Seattle',
  employee_count: 85
}]
```

What makes the most sense for the uri, then? Still /locations? Or maybe /employees/locations?

My concern is that calculating employee_count with each request to /locations could ensue additional, wasteful overhead, as employee_count may only be used 5 - 10% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it in either place, or in both. Your application's needs should dictate that choice.

The more important thing about your proposed design is the fact that your individual location objects don't contain a URI in order for the client to navigate to each location to get more detailed information about them.

Instead you've included only an ID, which presumably you're expecting the client to use to construct a location-specific URI? If so, you should strongly consider adding a full URI to the payload for each location (say, "link" or "href"). Without that method in place, you'll be coupling your clients to the structure of your URIs and making a future evolution of your system more difficult. FYI, this approach is typically called [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) (Hypermedia As The Engine Of Application State).